# non-nested sections

Tags: sectioning

I can get sections that are not nested in `\part` with

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
```

but although `\chapter` gets compiled, it is typeset indistinguishably from text. I can get chapters that are typeset as such using

```
\documentclass{report}
```

but then sections are nested inside chapters. Is there a way out of this dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to update the representation of the respective counters. Here's how the hierarchical counter representations are defined within `article`:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

You can remove `\thesection` [`\thesubsection`] from `\thesubsection` [`\thesubsubsection`] to visually separate the hierarchy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Remove hierarchical display of sectional units
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\subsection{Final subsection}
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Yet another subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Final subsubsection}
\section{Final section}

\end{document}
```

Note that only the visual display of the hierarchy is removed. The interaction between the sectional units still exist, such as the `subsection` [`subsubsection`] counter being reset with every new `\section` [`\subsection`].

Answer (score 0):

If you process

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\part{This is the first part}

\section{A section}

\section{Another section}

\part{This is the second part}

\section{Yet another section}

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

Note that `extarticle` is essentially the same as `article`, it just allows for a wider choice of font sizes.

If you want the same behavior with `report` so you can use `\chapter` instead of `\part`, use `\counterwithout`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is the first chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{Another section}

\chapter{This is the second chapter}

\section{Yet another section}

\end{document}
```

[image]